# How Do I Get The Currently Running Activity In My Application?

Tags: android, view, android-activity

I have a class that needs to access my application's main activity, but by design outside of my control I cannot pass an instance to it. Its purpose is to dynamically create a view and set it to the activity.

Is there a way for me to access the main activity through a static method? Or is there an alternative?

Comment: Can you explain why you can't pass the activity/context to your class? Surely you would be constructing it somewhere, and you can pass the context down to the constructor.

Comment: Since Android creates the Activity instance for you, and it can be recreated at any time when the memory situation requires it, it doesn't make sense to have a static pointer to it.  If you explain why you need access to the activity, what you are actually trying to accomplish, we might be able to point you in the right direction.  From what you have said, it sounds like the Activity should have access to your class, not the other way around.

Comment: The application is NDK based. The C++ code creates an instance of my Java class through JNI. The Java class, in theory, creates a WebView. Neither the C++ code nor the Java class ever get passed the main activity.

Comment: Why does the Java class create a WebView, instead of the Activity creating a web view?  It sounds like you want to start the Activity with some parameters, perhaps using intent extras?

Comment: My main application is an NDK based game. It doesn't need a WebView all the time. The WebView would be created the moment the user clicks on an item in the main menu and go away when done.

Comment: Also, the described WebView functionality is part of a standalone library used by game clients. Game clients won't work at the Java level, but at the C++ level. However they still require high level features like a webview.

Comment: It still sounds like all you need to do is create a new Activity when the user clicks on the item in the menu, where the new Activity will display a webView.  When they hit back on that Activity to get back to the game, the WebView will go away. Does that fit your usecase?  Btw, for game specific questions, check out gamedev.stackexchange.com as an alternate resource.

Comment: Would the new Activity require a parent of some kind? This is basically what I'm missing. A solution that doesn't require some kind of parent object that I don't have access to is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a parent.  You would need access to a `Context` to be able to request that the Activity be started.  I don't have any experience with the NDK, so I'm not sure how exactly it interacts with the standard application context, but I assume there is a way to do so.

Comment: That's the problem with the NDK. There is no way to do it. I would be happy to be corrected. By "parent object", I meant that no object I'd need (activity, context, etc) can be created without passing another object, its parent, in its constructor.

Comment: You should be able to make a remote call to an object that has an instance of the context though.  Have you looked through all the ndk samples?  It seems like one of them should cover this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments above, maybe you need just static instance of context initialized in Application/Activity onCreate?

Comment: I went with this kind solution.